# How to place pandas data frame header names in a specific order?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, import

So I try to import a number of excels and create a list of all the data and here is my code for it:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
cwd = os.path.abspath('') 
files = os.listdir(cwd)  
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.XLSX'):
        df = df.append(pd.read_excel(file), ignore_index=True)

df = df.where(df.notnull(), None)
array = df.values.tolist()
print(array)
```

the excels, on the other hand, look something like so:

```
    product cost   used_by prime
    name    price  gender  yes or no
    name    price  gender  yes or no
    ... and so on
```

However, not all of them have the odder of `product cost  used_by prime`(case one order). Some of them, for example, are in the format of `cost product prime used_by`(case two order). Of course, pandas would be able to auto-sort them and make sure the data find the right header, but I run into an issue.

So basically, I run this code on two different devices using the same data and code but the results are different. One of them is in case one order while the other one is in the case two order. I want to have a line of code that makes sure the data frame is always in the order of `product cost  used_by prime` but I am not sure how.

Can you show me the python code for it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try reordering right after loading the csv file

```
df = df[['product', 'used_by', 'prime']]
```